# Rails 3.2: Ordering a has_many :through selection, when the through-model has a default_scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple time-tracking app, that has projects, tasks, and entries.

The setup is straight-forward:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::base
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :entries, :through => :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :entries

  default_scope order("name asc") # this causes problems
end
```

(`Entry` is entirely straight-forward, so I've left it out)

However, I'm running into trouble when trying to do custom ordering of entries selected from a project. Specifically, I'm trying to select the latest entry like so:

```
latest_entry = project.entries.order("created_at desc").first
```

But due to the `:through => :tasks` and the `default_scope` that `Task` has, the actual query that Rails executes becomes:

```
SELECT `entries`.* FROM `entries`
INNER JOIN `tasks` ON `entries`.`task_id` = `tasks`.`id`
WHERE `tasks`.`project_id` = 23
ORDER BY name asc, entries.date desc LIMIT 1 -- wrong order!
```

Note the `ORDER BY clause` - it includes the `default_scope` from `Task`, and only after that does it include the order I specified.

So basically, I *don't* get the latest entry of all entries in the project, but only the latest in the first task.

Is there any way around that? Seems like there should be a way to ignore/negate `default_scope` on a `through`-model (without completely dropping the `default_scope`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [reorder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder):

```
latest_entry = project.entries.reorder("created_at desc").first
```

Comment: Ok, so I'm an moron -- honestly, I don't how I've missed that method. Been looking at the docs, but apparently... well, I'm a moron. Nuff' said :) -- thank you!

Comment: came across the same issue. Is there a way to apply this `reorder` by default when you access `project.entries`. Setting `:has_many :entries, :through => :tasks, :order => '...'` applies this order after the default scope order.